# Services similiar to S3 to store pictures accesible from an Android app

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I'm developing an Android app to show details and pictures about some hotels. I built a Rails back-end deployed in OpenShift and my idea was to store the pictures in AWS S3 and make them accessible from the Android app.
Due to the complexity of AWS,Cognito,IAM,STS,Role and Trust policies, I'm thinking maybe I should reconsider the idea of using S3; but I don't know which service I should consider. 
I need only a place where to store the pictures and then making them accessible from the app; something like S3, but easier to use.
I'm thinking of Parse but I'm quite new to it. 
Do you have some hint?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that you think Cognito is too complex for your use case. Could you please share why you think that?

Comment: Sure Bob!just think about all the reading I've to do about Cognito,IAM,Roles and STS(and more). Most of the stuff aren't clearly explained, examples don't work, the articles are too simplistic for a real-world use and there is also some outdated article. I should understand a really big architecture but what I want is just a bucket accessible from an Android app. I've been using AWS Services from the beginning and loved it but now (as a freelancer) I can't spend 3 days reading all the stuff I need to understand an operation that should be [almost] straightforward.

Comment: For example, for my simple problem I should understand what Idenity pool, Cognito, IAM, TST, Roles and Trust policy are and how they work together. How much learning-time does each involve? Cognito is a tool supposed to simplify our developer work but in my case it has been the opposite. Just go the the github S3 transfer manager demo and read the 'Set Up Permissions' steps: how much knowledge is hiding each step? In my case I evaluate it doesn't worth spending more time on it. For someone else maybe it worth ;) (like I did in the past)

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but we recently published a blog on [basic Cognito Authentication](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication), which should give you the the important details on the auth flow. I'd be curious to know what you think would help further simplify and make Cognito a good fit for your use case as it's definitely one we want to support.

Comment: Bob> The entire configuration of setting up Cognito/IAM/Groups/Policies/Roles/Bucket-Policies - is way too complex even for unauthenticated user case. There are just too many things to deal with for a simple app. One way could be: Provide a default setup - which users can change if needed.

Comment: Dr Duke> What did you finally use?

Comment: Jasper, I'm finally storing the pictures in my server. I don't like and It's a temporary solution and I did have no time to look for others. I wish Amazon will provide a default setup as you said.

Comment: Bob, sorry to reply late. I read the article (when you wrote down the link here) and it's still confusing and take too much time to setup the most simple of buckets.

Comment: If you want to support freelance like me, just think I've to read lot of stuff of everything (Android,JSON,Rails,Openshift) and I don't have the option of spending 1 day just to know what IAM is because I'll use S3 only like a container and I cannot care about all the options it offers. 
But what it makes me really sad is that I worked with AWS!and I did setup buckets just in a few hours, EC2s, communications between EC2 and S3..without hassle in the past.